# Why is Only One Object Appearing in my Database? (Using Spring and MongoDB)

Tags: java, html, spring, mongodb, crud

I am working on an ecommerce website using Eclipse, Spring, and MongoDB. Whenever I try creating a new category (URL is http://localhost:8080/admin/categories), the first one appears, but when I try creating a new one, it just replaces my first one. For example, if I create a category called "car", it appears, but then when I create a new one called "bike", the latter takes the place of the former. I of course want category car to be first and category bike to be second. I am assuming it has something to do with the id not saving properly because in my MongoDB collection, the entry shows nothing for _id (normally it does show something for _id).

[image: MongoDB Picture]

Here is my code:

```
package com.ecommerce.website.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.ecommerce.website.model.Category;
import com.ecommerce.website.service.CategoryService;

@Controller
public class AdminController {
    
    //Injecting dependency
    @Autowired
    CategoryService categoryService;
    
    //This method maps for /admin endpoint. It shows the adminHome.html page. The method is @GetMapping because you are getting information 
    //@return the adminHome page
    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String adminHome() {
        
        //Display html page
        return "adminHome";
    }
    
    //This method maps for /admin/categories endpoint. It shows the categories.html page. The method is @GetMapping because you are getting information
    //@return the categories page 
    @GetMapping("/admin/categories")
    public String getCat(Model model) {
        
        model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.getAllCategories());
        
        //Display html page
        return "categories";
    }
    
    //This method maps for /admin/categories endpoint. It shows the categoriesAdd.html page, but before that, it creates
    //a model that is sent to the html file via Thymeleaf. The categoriesAdd.html page is a form for adding a category
    //The method is @GetMapping because you are getting information
    //@param model will hold the category object so that the form can add information to it 
    //@return the categoriesAdd page 
    @GetMapping("/admin/categories/add")
    public String getCatAdd(Model model) {
        
        //Adding the model name "category", and creating a new Category object and putting it in the model
        model.addAttribute("newCategory", new Category());
        
        //Display html page
        return "categoriesAdd";
    }
    
    //This method maps for /admin/categories endpoint. It allows the user to add a category to the list of categories
    //The method is @PostMapping because you are sending information
    //@param category gets its value from the ModelAttribute, which gets its value from the form
    //@return the categories page 
    @PostMapping("/admin/categories/add")
    public String postCatAdd(@ModelAttribute("newCategory") Category category) {
        
        //Calling categoryService to add the category
        categoryService.addCategory(category);
        
        //Redirecting to page that shows all categories 
        return "redirect:/admin/categories";
    }
    
    
}
```

```
package com.ecommerce.website.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.ecommerce.website.model.Category;
import com.ecommerce.website.repository.CategoryRepository;

@Service
public class CategoryService {

    //Injecting dependency 
    @Autowired
    CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    
    //This method calls categoryRepository to add a category to the database  
    //@param category is the category that is being added 
    public void addCategory(Category category) {
        
        //Saving the category to the database 
        categoryRepository.save(category);
    }
    
    //This method calls categoryRepository to retrieve a list of categories 
    //@return the list of categories  
    public List<Category> getAllCategories() {
        return categoryRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

```
package com.ecommerce.website.repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import com.ecommerce.website.model.Category;

public interface CategoryRepository extends MongoRepository<Category, String> {

}
```

```
package com.ecommerce.website.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "categories")
public class Category {
    
    @Id
    private String id;
    
    
    private String name;
    
    
    public Category() {
        
    }
    
    public Category(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 
    
    
}
```

This is the page that is supposed to show all the categories

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" >
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img th:src="@{/images/logo.png}"  src="../static/images/logo.png" width="auto" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""/>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    
                    <!-- This anchor allows the user to go to the admin home page. It maps to the method with
                         /admin endpoint -->
                    <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/admin}" href="#">admin-home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                
                    <!-- This anchor allows the user to logout. It maps to the method with
                         /logout endpoint -->
                    <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/logout}" href="#">logout</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">

    <!-- This anchor allows the user to go to the categoriesAdd page. It maps to the method with
         /admin/categories/add endpoint -->
    <a th:href="@{/admin/categories/add}" style="margin: 20px 0" class="btn btn-primary">Add Category</a>
    <table class="table">
        
        <!-- Creating the table heads -->
        <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">SN</th>
            <th scope="col">Category Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Delete</th>
            <th scope="col">Update</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <!-- Looping through each category and displaying its name (iStat is responsible for the serial numbers) -->
        <tr th:each="category, iStat : ${categories}">
        
            <!-- iStat.index is 0th index, so we add 1 so that the SN's start at 1 -->
            <th scope="row" th:text="${iStat.index + 1}">1</th>
            <td th:text="${category.name}">Larry</td>
            
            <!-- ????Buttons: first deletes the product; second maps to the /update endpoint, which takes the user to edit.html
                         for whichever product the product.id is for (id is appended to the URL, which is how the /show endpoint
                         is able to access it -->
            <td><a href="" th:href="@{/admin/categories/delete/{id}(id=${category.id})}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
            <td><a href="" th:href="@{/admin/categories/update/{id}(id=${category.id})}" class="btn btn-warning">Update</a></td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the page for adding a new category

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" >
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img th:src="@{/images/logo.png}"  src="../static/images/logo.png" width="auto" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""/>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/admin}" href="#">admin-home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/logout}" href="#">logout</a>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        
            <!-- Mapping to the /admin/categories/add endpoint (@PostMapping one). We are using post method since we are 
                 sending info. The category object comes from the getCatAdd() method -->
            <!-- This is the real work: send form data to /admin/categories/add. "category" is the model attribute -->
            <form th:action="@{/admin/categories/add}" method="post" th:object="${newCategory}">
            
                <!-- Hidden id field to show which category is being added. It will bind to ModelAttribute to tell your app
                     which category is being added. *{category_id} selects category_id property on referenced th:object (category)  -->
                <input type="hidden" name="id" th:field="*{id}">
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    
                    <!-- Input field. *{name} selects name property on referenced th:object (category) -->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required th:field="*{name}" name="name" id="name"  placeholder="Enter name">

                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IMO, you should have your id field with some annotations like `@GeneratedValue` and `@SequenceGenerator` and provider them with a sequence generator of your choice, so you will have a auto generate id each time you insert a new record

Comment: Thank you! I tried adding "@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)" above my id in the Category POJO, but it is still not allowing me to add multiple categories to the database.

Comment: Why not use the default ObjectId that mongo generates?

Comment: I tried using it, but it still only shows me one object in my database. It's weird because I have another POJO called Product in my project, and the id works properly for that.

Comment: When you browse to the add category page, what value does the hidden 'id' field have?  Is it always the same?

Comment: This is what I have for the hidden field so far: <input type="hidden" name="id" th:field="*{id}">. Is it supposed to be like this?